# C (OSDev) - How could I shift the contents of a 32-bit framebuffer upwards efficiently?

Tags: c, framebuffer, osdev

I'm working on writing a hobby operating system.  Currently a large struggle that I'm having is attempting to scroll the framebuffer upwards.
It's simply a 32-bit linear framebuffer.
I have access to a few tools that could be helpful:

- some of the mem* functions from libc: `memset`, `memcpy`, `memmove`, and `memcmp`
- direct access to the framebuffer
- the width, height, and size in bytes, of said framebuffer
- a previous attempt that managed to scroll it up a few lines, albeit EXTREMELY slowly, it took roughly 25 seconds to scroll the framebuffer up by 5 pixels

speaking of which, my previous attempt:

```
for (uint64_t i = 0; i != atoi(numLines); i++) {
    for (uint64_t j = 0; j != bootboot.fb_width; j++) {
        for (uint64_t k = 1; k != bootboot.fb_size; k++) {
            ((uint32_t *)&fb)[k - 1] = ((uint32_t *)&fb)[k];
        }
    }
}
```

A few things to note about the above:

- `numLines` is a variable passed into the function, it's a `char *` that contains the number of lines to scroll up by, in a string.  I eventually want this to be the number of actual text lines to scroll up by, but for now treating this as how many pixels to scroll up by is sufficient.
- the `bootboot` struct is provided by the bootloader I use, it contains a few variables that could be of use: `fb_width` (the width of the framebuffer), `fb_height` (the height of the framebuffer), and `fb_size` (the size, in bytes, of the framebuffer)
- the `fb` variable that I'm using the address of is also provided by the bootloader I use, it is a single byte that is placed at the first byte of the framebuffer, hence the need to cast it into a `uint32_t *` before using it.

**Any and all help would be appreciated.**

Comment: first thought - 25 seconds is huge. mayebe the hw locks access to the video buffer? is there some way to suspend the io.

Comment: @pm100 yeah it really is huge, but to be fair, it's trying to move a whole 32-bit framebuffer (looks like qemu is using 1024x768), one byte at a time, also, qemu might be adding a decent amount of overhead there.  But no, I can confirm that nothing is locking access to the framebuffer.  The GPU will simply draw the contents when it's ready (to confirm, that's when the GPU is ready, not when the kernel is ready, there's no form of vsync in here).

Comment: the main problem is that you're shifting each pixel by one pixel at a time multiple times, what you actually want - for every pixel calculate its new final position, so if you want to move 5 pixels up, you want to take pixel (x 0, y 5) at fb[0 + 5*fb_width] and copy it to pixel (0, 0) fb[0], pixel at (1, 5) to (1, 0) == [1 + 5*fb_width] -> [1], thus you will copy each pixel one time only

Comment: Would memmove() solve all of your problems? If supported on your platform, I'm sure it will be super-optimised.

Comment: Instead of using memmove and potentially reading from video memory (which is slow), it's recommnded to use a double framebuffer. Create a buffer in memory that has the same size as the video framebuffer, and write to that instead. Introduce an offset variable. When you need to scroll, simply increase the offset variable by the amount of bytes for one row, copy from that offset to the end to video fb, then copy from 0 to offset. That will be more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read the code correctly, what's happening with the triple nested loops is:

1. For every line to scroll,
2. For every pixel that the framebuffer is wide,
3. For every pixel in the entire framebuffer,
4. Move that pixel backwards by one.

Essentially you're moving each pixel one pixel distance at a time, so it's no wonder it takes so long to scroll the framebuffer.  The total number of pixel moves is `(numLines * fb_width * fb_size)`, so if your framebuffer is 1024x768, that's `5*1024*1024*768` moves, which is 4,026,531,840 moves. That's basically 5000 times the amount of work required.

Instead, you'll want to loop over the framebuffer only once, calculate that pixel's start and its end pointer, and only do the move once.  Or you can calculate the source, destination, and size of the move once and then use memmove.  Here's my attempt at this (with excessive comments):

```
 // Convert string to integer
uint32_t numLinesInt = atoi(numLines);
 // The destination of the move is just the top of the framebuffer
uint32_t* destination = (uint32_t*)&fb;
 // Start the move from the top of the framebuffer plus however
 // many lines we want to scroll.
uint32_t* source = (uint32_t*)&fb +
    (numLinesInt * bootboot.fb_width);
 // The total number of pixels to move is the size of the
 // framebuffer minus the amount of lines we want to scroll.
uint32_t pixelSize = (bootboot.fb_height - numLinesInt)
    * bootboot.fb_width;
 // The total number of bytes is that times the size of one pixel.
uint32_t byteSize = pixelSize * sizeof(uint32_t);
 // Do the move
memmove(destination, source, byteSize);
```

I haven't tested this, and I'm making a number of assumptions about how your framebuffer is laid out, so please make sure it works before using it. :)

(P.S. Also, if you put `atoi(numLines)` inside the end condition of the for loop, `atoi` will be called every time through the loop, instead of once at the beginning like you intended.)

Comment: This actually *almost* works perfectly!  Only 1 issue:
The memmove call is messed up, you're passing `byte_size` twice, modifying it to the following fixes it:
`memmove(destination, source, byte_size);`
Thank you so much for the help.  I marked your answer as accepted.

Comment: My apologies, I must have been getting it confused with memmove_s on this page https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memmove.  Also I seem not to have enough reputation to review suggested edits, so I can't accept the edit suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

> Currently a large struggle that I'm having is attempting to scroll the framebuffer upwards.

The first problem is that the framebuffer is typically much slower to access than RAM (especially reads); so you want to do all the drawing in a buffer in RAM and then blit it efficiently (with a smaller number of much larger writes).

Once you have a buffer in RAM, you can make the buffer bigger than the screen. E.g. for a 1024 x 768 video mode you might have a 1024 x 1024 buffer. In that case small amounts of scrolling can often be done using the same "blit it efficiently" function; but sometimes you'll have to scroll the buffer in RAM.

To scroll the buffer in RAM you can cheat - treat it as a circular buffer and map a second copy into virtual memory immediately after the first. This allows you to (e.g.) copy 768 lines starting from the middle of the first copy without caring about hitting the end of the first buffer. The end result is that you can scroll the buffer in RAM without moving any data or changing the "blit it efficiently" function.

As a bonus, this also minimizing "tearing" artifacts. E.g. often you want to scroll the pixel data up and add more pixel data to the bottom, then blit it (without the user seeing an intermediate "half finished" frame).